# Oauth 2 on an Android app

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0

So i need to be able to use Oauth for the login part on my Android application(not for Twitter, google,etc...) it's a private application. The rest of the app uses rest services w/ the authenticated token.

Here basically i'm looking for any tips, a library or an article recommendation. Most of the articles i found are about how to login to Google's services and such.

Thanks,

Comment: @JustinVartanian Broken Link :(

Answer (score 5):

Check this one: [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) It is pretty simple.

Here it is a list of libraries cited by the Oauth2.0 "authority":

[oauth.net/2](http://oauth.net/2/)

Comment: I know that this is outdated but i'd like to know if scribe would work with any API which use OAuth, not just those of the spoken in the doc. Thx